# Keeping Swift Double precision in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

A double created in Swift

```
let d: Double = 1.0
```

when passed to Objective C, will not preserve the `.0`. It ends up as `1`.

Is there a way preserve `.0` for whole doubles in Objective C?

Edit:

Here's what I'm doing:

`Parent.m`

```
 @implementation Parent

-(void)log:(NSDictionary*)data {
}

 @end
```

`Parent.h`

```
@interface Parent : NSObject

-(void)log:(NSDictionary*)data;

@end
```

`Child.swift`

```
class Child: Parent {

    func log() {
      let measure = Double(1)
      let isLoggedIn = false
      let data: [String: Any] = ["is_logged_in": isLoggedIn, "measure": measure]
      log(data) // calling parent method, measure ends up as 1
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on how are you handling it in Objective-C. Show your Obj-C code for better help.

Comment: You are still missing how you are handling data in `log` method in Obj-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wording of your question you might need to research the difference between a *double value* (the same in both languages) and a *textual representation of a double value* (which your question suggests might not default to the same in both languages).

Once you are clear on that look up the `NSString` method `stringWithFormat` and see if you can produce the format you require using that. (`NSLog()` supports the same formatting.)

If the above fails to meet your requirements look up `NSNumberFormatter`.

HTH